# Can't parse date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have a problem to filter range of dates [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/VZizdhY8RS9Eqp9JyOio?p=preview)  is the project. The filter works fine but when i try to filter the flowing dates 01/08/2016 and 01/09/2016 - the filter returns false.

At the beginning i thought something is worng with the filter's conditions:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {

    var min = new Date($('#filter_start_date').val());
    var max = new Date($('#filter_end_date').val());
    var date_var =   new Date(data[4]); // use data for the date column

    if (
        ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
        ( isNaN( min ) && date_var <= max ) ||
        ( min <= date_var   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
        ( min <= date_var   && date_var <= max )
        )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;


}
```

);

But the i realize that it's probably something to do with the parsing of the dates...

Answer (score 0):

`dateString` in `new Date(dateString)` must be in certain format to work properly, please see, for example, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for some guidelines.

A quick fix to make your example work is to change `dateFormat` in `datepicker` options:

```
...    
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
...
```

If you do not like the displayed format, there are options in `datepicker` to change that.

Comment: Thanks - but is didn't worked - just to change the date format - i had to filter the dates with yymmdd format - and it's solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Got it - i changed the filter format to yy-mm-dd like this :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
 function(settings, data, dataIndex) {

 function reverse_date(inputDate){

        var date_to_fix = inputDate.split("/");
        var fixed = date_to_fix.reverse().join('-');

        return fixed; // creates yy-mm-dd format
    };

var min = new Date(reverse_date($('#filter_start_date').val()));
var max = new Date(reverse_date($('#filter_end_date').val()));
var date_var = new Date(reverse_date((data[4]))); // use data for the age 
column

if (
  (isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
  (isNaN(min) && date_var <= max) ||
  (min <= date_var && isNaN(max)) ||
  (min <= date_var && date_var <= max)
) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

}
);

And it solved the problem.
[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VZizdhY8RS9Eqp9JyOio?p=preview) is the project.